# How large would an African Grey Parrot have to be to be smarter than the average human?

Tags: biology, evolution, avian, sapience

African Grey Parrots are touted as the smartest genus of birds around, and have been shown to possess cognitive skills comparable to those of 4- to 6-year-old human children, in spite of only weighing in at 0.85-1.15lbs, and only possessing brains roughly the size of walnuts. So, just how much larger and heavier would a hypothetical *Psittacus* parrot species have to be for its cognitive skills to realistically rival, or surpass, those of the average human?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer. They can be whatever size you want; you've just proven in your own question that brain size itself has little to no relationship to intelligence itself.

Comment: @Aify Oh, come now. Brain size, and brain size-body mass ratio, always has a heavy correlation with intelligence. I'm asking for a rough estimate in a world with hard science. A human 5yo child's brain's 90% the size than of an adult human; does that mean that Grey Parrots could hypothetically only have brains 10% larger and be as smart as humans? Or 20% larger, and be smarter than humans to the same degree that we're smarter than them? And would either be believable enough for a reading audience to take it seriously?

Comment: Brains just don't scale like this, which makes the question nonsensical. If you have the same amount of neurons and synapses, only they're bigger, presumably it works about the same. If you glob a bunch of extra neurons on it, well, nobody knows what would happen or if it would even function. A child is also not less capable than an adult because its brain is smaller.

Comment: Just making the animal bigger does not make the brain to body ration any larger, this it is not making it any smarter. If you double a chimps size is doesn't make it any smarter. This is really easy to see in humans, people with gigantism are not smarter than people with dwarfism.

Comment: Where is your evidence that there is a "heavy" correlation? On the other hand, there are very good examples of there being little correlation; Apes are not nearly as smart as humans are, yet our brain/body mass ratios are strikingly similar. Ants have a ratio of approx 1:7 (B to BM), hippos are 1:2789, shrews are 1:10, mice are 1:40, lions 1:550, and elephants 1:560. Yet all those creatures are significantly more stupid than humans, who clock in at 1:50. I see no relationship whatsoever.

Comment: @Aify:  Re "Apes are not nearly as smart as humans...", I think you could find a number of humans for whom this is not so.

Answer (score 1):

The first and most fundamental problem here is in defining just what is meant by "cognitive skills".  As one (fictional) parrot of my acquaintance so aptly says, "I can talk.  Can you fly?"  So what's your unbiased by a human perspective definition of cognitive skills?  How do you measure these skills?

I would bet you're going to start with language, but how much of language is abstract "cognitive skill", and how much is simply the possession of a specialized brain area and vocal cords?  Some unintelligent people can talk quite well (note how I manfully resist the temptation to cite political examples here :-)); many very intelligent (at least in their speciality) aren't all that articulate.  People can suffer strokes or other brain injuries that impair language but not intelligence: https://www.aphasia.org/

OK, how about math?  Basic arithmetic?  Well, take the case of Clever Hans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans  Hans (a horse) was supposed to have been taught to do simple arithmetic, but was shown to instead be responding to subtle, involuntary cues on the part of the questioner.  So which involves more cognitive skill, arithmetic or learning by observation to detect those cues and respond appropiately?  Perhaps some humans could do the same, but I'm pretty sure that I'm not one of them.

Or to take it a little further, humans all have roughly the same size brains.  How many of us can use them to do say tensor calculus?  Or figure out something really complicated (IMHO, anyway), like knitting?